# GWT-platform different between Action and Event

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

In GWT-platform, what is the different between Action and Event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concepts of event is a bit wider than action. 
Each action can be associated with some event but an action isn't necessarily for a occurrence of defined event.
An **action** is any action of the user. And an **event** is a result of user action (UI event) or performing of some conditions (other event).
For example, a user did the *action* `press button`. This action can be associated with an *event* `button was pressed`. And for example, a *event* `expiration of user session` doesn't require any action.

But these terms are very similar in meaning for GWT and I suppose sometimes many developers use they interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Actions are objects that represent a client-server command. Actions are sent from the client to the server using GWTP's dispatcher (DispatchAsync). Actions will be treated server-side, using an Action Handler. Actions can have asynchronous callbacks, for client-side treatment of successful or failed action handling.

Events are objects used on the client side. They are fired (ideally from a Presenter or a PresenterWidget) and are broadcasted to other Presenter/PresenterWidgets through the EventBus.  Other Presenter/PresenterWidgets can subscribe to a particular Event type, and take action whenever an Event of that type is fired across the EventBus. It is an implementation of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

In GWT-platform, Actions refer to server-side calls (to fetch/alter data between client and server). 
Events is only on client-side. They could be used for manual reveal of presenters, or to update some text somewhere.

This is at least the way I use them.